# Convert A JSON file into java objects when web server starts

Tags: java, json

I have one JSON file i am converting it to JAVA Object using Object Mapper as given below :-

```
String agentName = Request.getAgentName();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
agent = mapper.readValue(new File(agentName), Agent.class);
```

these is working fine, but the problem is, for each and every request i am converting json to java object, I want to do it one time when my web server starts.
How can i do it, these is a rest application.

Comment: make `agent` static and don't do unless `agent` is `null` ? - needs to be synchronized

Comment: You can add agent in Singleton Class .

Comment: Undertake upon startup in ServletContextListener

Comment: Hi @ScaryWombat thanks for the reply, actually i have like 10 to 20 agents, which are written is JSON and i want their java objects when the server starts, and i do not want to do it for each request, its like i want to do it as a initialization process.

Comment: So, can't you implement a Singleton with a map of agents by name and if the value is `null` initialize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a possible solution using a Singleton class with a map holding all your agents initialized on request.

```java
public class Agents {

    private static Agents theInstance;

    private final Map<String, Agent> AGENTS_MAP;

    private Agents() {
        this.AGENTS_MAP = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static Agents getInstance() {
        if (theInstance == null) {
            theInstance = new Agents();
        }

        return theInstance;
    }

    public Agent getAgent(String agentName) {
        if (!AGENTS_MAP.containsKey(agentName) {
            initAgent(agentName);
        }

        return AGENTS_MAP.get(agentName);
    }

    // TODO handle errors
    private static void initAgent(String agentName) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Agent agent = mapper.readValue(new File(agentName), Agent.class);
        AGENTS_MAP.put(agentName, agent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have a map *and* an instance?

Comment: The class is called Agent**s** and holds all `Agent` instances, since Arvind said "i have like 10 to 20 agents". A better name can be used for the singleton class.

Comment: Hi @noiaverbale i will your class in ServletContextListener, since it will be called only once when the server is started, no need to make it singleton in my case, can you see my answer and suggest any edits?

Comment: Even if you initialize all `Agent`s in `ServletContextListener`, you'll need to call the singleton class (holding all already initialized agents) where you need it. If you don't want `Agents` to be a singleton, you have to set `AGENTS_MAP` and `getAgent()` as static, but I don't think this is an ideal scenario.

Comment: I have a seperate class named as AgentManager, which has  the following static method  getAgent and insertAgentToCache, the method insertAgentToCache inserts the agent into the private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Agent> agentCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Agent>();, i just called these method in ServletContextListener class and it does my work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PostConstruct` to initialization of your variables:

```
@PostConstruct 
public void initApplication() {
    String agentName = Request.getAgentName();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    agent = mapper.readValue(new File(agentName), Agent.class); 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Spara i do not want to use spring, I think as suggested by ScaryWombat i will go for ServletContextListener

Answer (score 0):

I think these will work, i will create an object of agents class in my ServletContextListner class and under the method contextInitialized, i will create object of agents class by passing the list of all the agents.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.ipaylabs.eme.vo.main.Agent;

public class Agents {
    private static Agents theInstance;
    private static Map<String, Agent> AGENTS_MAP;

    public Agents(String[] agentList) {
        this.AGENTS_MAP = new HashMap<>();
        for(String agentName : agentList) {
            initAgent(agentName);
        } 
    }

    public Agent getAgent(String agentName) {
        if (!AGENTS_MAP.containsKey(agentName)) {
            initAgent(agentName);
        }
        return AGENTS_MAP.get(agentName);
    }


    private static void initAgent(String agentName) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Agent agent = null;
        try {
            agent = mapper.readValue(new File(agentName), Agent.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AGENTS_MAP.put(agentName, agent);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat these is what you are talking about, am i right?